# Log In page and Sign Up page i need to put all in one page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css

I have two different page 
the first Page where i have the form with
   email:
   password:

and the second page have all the normal questions for a sign up.

I need to put all in a single page with a box splited in 2 vertical coloumns.

All the page are in .aspx and the forms have this declaration:

Sign Up:

```
        <div id="main-area">
        <div id="main-panel">
            <div class="table-heading teal">Welcome to the Registration Page</div>


                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
```

Login page

```
        <div id="main-area">
        <div id="main-panel">
            <div class="table-heading teal">Login</div>
                <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
```

I think i had to create a css with #main-panel-sx and a #main-panel-dx with a width of the 50%. But if i do that the page go wrong with a problem to the asp code

Comment: What CSS code are you using? The problem must lay there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table and add table cells and rows and define controls in your cells accordingly.